# Laravel how do I get the process percentage when I upload on digital ocean?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, upload, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I have a large input file for 200MB-1GB, which will be uploaded in digital ocean, I want the process percentage to appear, for that I have to get the percentage, is there a way?
here is my code to upload to digital ocean

```
 $name = Str::uuid();
 $extension = $request->file('url')->extension();
 $fullname=$name.'.'.$extension;
 $disk = Storage::disk('digitalocean');
 $disk->put($fullname, fopen(request()->file('url'), 'r+'),'public');
```